# Is there a way to prevent cordova from overwriting my assets files?

Tags: cordova

Anytime I add a new plugin cordova overwrites all my assets/www files.
Is there a way to tell cordova not to do this?
Many thx

Comment: Don't develop in the platform files, only in the root www of your project.

Comment: And then how do I sync my updates?

Comment: Read the documentation! Do a cordova build or use symlinks or use prebuild scripts. There is no other way. If there are not very special reasons, leave the platform folders untouched. The most things in there will be overridden by every build.

Comment: every time you build through command prompt or terminal ... then assent will change... so after installing plugin dont build the app through cmd or terminal...

Comment: Well I'm not able to find any proper guide on Android Studio with Cordova, it's all either outdated or not relevant on the process to adopt ... Anyone to provide me a good link to a relevant tutorial?

Comment: Don't use android studio, use just the cordova CLI. If you are only going to target android and never other platforms, then instead of using the cordova CLI, use just the cordova android platform scripts and the you'll be able to use android studio as you want, but you will have to use plugman to install the plugins instead of using the cordova CLI